# Can I say "I was seeing Lucy last Sunday"

Tags: grammar, expressions

And if I can, is the sentence

> I saw Lucy last Sunday.

any different?

Comment: Either one is valid syntax and reasonably idiomatic, assuming that "Lucy" is a live person.  If you're talking about the TV show then the title line would be a bit odd unless you followed up with something like "... when the news bulletin came on".  (And, in that case, "I was watching Lucy" would be more idiomatic.)

Comment: Also, you should be aware that "seeing" a potential romantic interest has possible connotations beyond simply having noted their presence somewhere.

Comment: Additionally, aside from the potential romantic connotation, "seeing" implies a longer and more meaningful encounter because it implies that the seeing occurred over time rather than in the literal sense of seeing someone, which could happen in a single instant.

Answer (score 1):

The progressive focuses more on the duration of the event than just its occurrance. So it would be natural to use this as a frame for some other event that took place while you were seeing her. The *seeing* used here would probably imply a meeting of sorts, not just noticing her with your eyes.

This could also involve a sort of progressive futurate in the past. Something like:

*I'm seeing the doctor Friday.*

would be the same as

*I have an appointment with the doctor on Friday*

So in that sense we could put together a sentence like:

*I was seeing Lucy last Sunday, so I went shopping for a new suit on Friday.*

Notice the time of *seeing Lucy* is after the time of *shopping for a new suit*.